# Multiple string replacements

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, replace

I've got a replacement map table

```
CREATE TABLE #ReplacementMap (old NVARCHAR(10), new NVARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #ReplacementMap VALUES ('A',5)
INSERT INTO #ReplacementMap VALUES ('C',9)
INSERT INTO #ReplacementMap VALUES ('D',4)
```

and a table of strings

```
CREATE TABLE #String1 (name NVARCHAR(50), string1 NVARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #String1 VALUES ('John','AB')
INSERT INTO #String1 VALUES ('Kyle','ABC')
INSERT INTO #String1 VALUES ('Steven','ABCD')
```

in which I need to replace bits of string based on the replacement map table so that I get the below results:

```
John,5B
Kyle,5B9
Steven,5B94
```

My current solution is to nest `REPLACE` function but due to the number of replacements that I need to do, it's not an elegant way to it.

Answer (score 3):

A SQLCLR function could be used to emulate the [`TRANSLATE` Transact-SQL function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql) new to SQL Server 2017.

#### Function definition

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [Translate] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
FROM 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
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Translate]
(
    @Input nvarchar(4000), 
    @Find nvarchar(4000), 
    @Replace nvarchar(4000)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(4000)
AS EXTERNAL NAME 
    [Translate].[UserDefinedFunctions].[Translate];
```

#### Usage

```
SELECT
    S.[name],
    S.string1,
    Result = dbo.Translate(S.string1, N'ACD', N'594')
FROM #String1 AS S;
```

```
╔════════╦═════════╦════════╗
║  name  ║ string1 ║ Result ║
╠════════╬═════════╬════════╣
║ John   ║ AB      ║ 5B     ║
║ Kyle   ║ ABC     ║ 5B9    ║
║ Steven ║ ABCD    ║ 5B94   ║
╚════════╩═════════╩════════╝
```

This simple demo implementation uses a case-sensitive comparison.

#### Source code

```cs
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [SqlFunction(
        DataAccess = DataAccessKind.None,
        IsDeterministic = true,
        IsPrecise = true,
        SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.None
    )]
    [return: SqlFacet(IsFixedLength = false, IsNullable = false, MaxSize = 4000)]
    public static SqlChars Translate
        (
            [SqlFacet(IsFixedLength = false, IsNullable = false, MaxSize = 4000)]
            SqlChars Input,
            [SqlFacet(IsFixedLength = false, IsNullable = false, MaxSize = 4000)]
            SqlChars Find,
            [SqlFacet(IsFixedLength = false, IsNullable = false, MaxSize = 4000)]
            SqlChars Replace
        )
    {
        if (Input.IsNull || Find.IsNull || Replace.IsNull)
        {
            // Return unchanged input for any NULL parameters
            return Input;
        }

        if (Find.Length != Replace.Length)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Find and Replace parameters must have the same length.");
        }

        // For each character in the input string
        for (int i = 0; i < Input.Length; i++)
        {
            // For each character in the Find string
            for (int j = 0; j < Find.Length; j++)
            {
                // If the character matches...
                if (Input[i] == Find[j])
                {
                    // ...replace it
                    Input[i] = Replace[j];
                }
            }
        }
        return Input;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can also be done with recursive SQL, although I can't say if it's a good idea to do so. I did add an `ID` column to your replacement map table. To test the code I generated 456976 four character strings:

```
CREATE TABLE #ReplacementMap (
ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1), 
old NVARCHAR(10),
new NVARCHAR(10),
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

INSERT INTO #ReplacementMap VALUES ('A',5);
INSERT INTO #ReplacementMap VALUES ('C',9);
INSERT INTO #ReplacementMap VALUES ('D',4);


CREATE TABLE #String1 (
ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
string1 NVARCHAR(100)
);

WITH ALL_LETTERS AS (
    SELECT distinct CHAR(number) LETTER
    FROM master..spt_values
    WHERE number >= 65 AND number <= 90
)
INSERT INTO #String1 WITH (TABLOCK)
SELECT a1.LETTER + a2.LETTER + a3.LETTER + a4.LETTER
FROM ALL_LETTERS a1
CROSS JOIN ALL_LETTERS a2
CROSS JOIN ALL_LETTERS a3
CROSS JOIN ALL_LETTERS a4;
```

Here is the code that does the translation:

```
WITH rec_cte AS (
    SELECT 
    s.ID
    , REPLACE(s.string1, rm.old, rm.new) new_string1
    , 1 replace_id
    FROM #String1 s
    INNER JOIN #ReplacementMap rm ON rm.ID = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
    s.ID
    , REPLACE(s.new_string1, rm.old, rm.new) new_string1
    , replace_id + 1
    FROM rec_cte s
    INNER JOIN #ReplacementMap rm ON rm.ID = replace_id + 1
)
SELECT ID, new_string1
FROM rec_cte
WHERE replace_id = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #ReplacementMap);
```

Suppose you have S rows in `#String1` and R rows in `#ReplacementMap`. For each row in `#ReplacementMap` we do a join to the table, filter to the next row, and `REPLACE()` using that row. Once there are no more rows in `#ReplacementMap` the full result set of S X R rows is returned. That is filtered down to the final translation by the subquery. The code will do S X R `REPLACE()` operations and R + 1 joins to a single row result set, along with some internal tempdb operations.

This should work without any modifications as long as you have less than 101 replacement strings. The code seems to perform similarly to the solution posted by Adán Bucio. On my machine this query finished in about 10 seconds and his solution finished in 20 seconds. However, you should not pick your solution on that basis. You should use whatever code you are most comfortable with, as long as it meets your response time requirements.

Note that SQL Server 2017 has a built-in function that makes this kind of operation trivial: [TRANSLATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql).

Answer (score 2):

You could use a recursive CTE for this job.
Your `string1` column value will be replaced item by item in `#ReplacementMap`

```
CREATE TABLE #ReplacementMap (old NVARCHAR(10), new NVARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #ReplacementMap VALUES ('A',5)
INSERT INTO #ReplacementMap VALUES ('C',9)
INSERT INTO #ReplacementMap VALUES ('D',4)

CREATE TABLE #String1 (name NVARCHAR(50), string1 NVARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #String1 VALUES ('John','AB')
INSERT INTO #String1 VALUES ('Kyle','ABC')
INSERT INTO #String1 VALUES ('Steven','ABCD')

DECLARE @MaxNumber int = (SELECT count(*) FROM #ReplacementMap)

;with temp AS
(
   SELECT *, row_number() over(order by rm.old) AS Rn
   FROM #ReplacementMap rm
)
,cte AS
(
   SELECT s.name, s.string1, CASt(0 AS int) AS Rn FROM #String1 s    
   UNION ALL
   SELECT cte.name, CAST(Replace(cte.string1,t.old, t.new) AS nvarchar(100))  , cte.Rn + 1 
   FROM cte 
   INNER JOIN temp t ON cte.Rn = t.Rn - 1
)
SELECT * FROM cte c
WHERE rn = @MaxNumber
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)


DROP TABLE #ReplacementMap
DROP TABLE #String1
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're replacing single chars you could split the string in single chars, join those with the replacement map and then concatenate back.

```
SELECT  ref.[name],
        ref.string1 AS original,
        rep.string  AS replaced
FROM    #String1 ref
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT  ISNULL(rm.new, 
                        SUBSTRING(ref.string1, num.number, 1)) AS [text()]
            FROM    master.dbo.spt_values num
                    LEFT JOIN #ReplacementMap rm
                        ON rm.old = SUBSTRING(ref.string1, num.number, 1)
            WHERE   num.number > 0 AND  num.number <= LEN(ref.string1)
                    AND num.[type] = 'P'
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ) rep(string);
```